# Is it possible to make file name with .html extension where php codes are included in the file?

Tags: php

I want to that if it is necessary to make files with `.php` extension or it is possible to add php codes into a file wiht `.html` extension.

Comment: If you have access to the server configuration; yes, otherwise; no. If yes, what is your server configuration?

Comment: no you can't.. php code should be in .php extended files

Comment: @BhuvanRikka i'm afraid, you are wrong... as Gerald mentioned, it's just a case of server configuration... so, technically, you can, if you can modify server config.

Comment: @MiroslavHudak Sorry i'm not aware of that. TFYI :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add PHP code to .html files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, at the following to the .htaccess file (assuming you're using Apache)

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .htm .html
```

**[More Info](http://websitedesign.websitesinaflash.com/2007/04/htaccess-addhandler/)**.

Take note that this is **not efficient** server-wise, as PHP will be fired for all pages in your script (you lose the ability to have high-efficiency static HTML web-pages, which are sometimes needed.

Comment: Very bad idea though - this will force web server to parse EVERY html page and check for presence of any PHP (or any other) server scripting. It will affect your server performance. Best to stick with std conventions. 
P.S. If you want to make your URL's prettier you can always use url rewriting.

Comment: @GermannArlington: Added that to my answer (before you wrote your comment actually ;P), that is correct. It is not very efficient.

Comment: Yes, I was never very fast typist.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your HTML extension of the file AND you want to use PHP code within the file, you MUST tell the webserver to do so by adding the .html extension and tell the webserver to let PHP handle it.

However, this is hugely inefficient, because PHP will be fired for each HTML request.