# processing PHP code on a .htm extension file?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add PHP code to .html files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files)

is there a way to process php code on a .html/.htm file? the server supports php I just need the file to retain the .htm extension

Note: I really don't understand why some users feel the need to down vote on a valid question. Not all questions appear in the search unless it worded close to the previous question.

Thanks for all the answers below. `AddType` in the htaccess solved my problem

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried the obvious `<?php ... ?>` around your PHP code within the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your .htaccess:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `mod_rewrite`, or add a directive to your **.htaccess** file to tell Apache (if that's what you're using) to add .htm as a PHP file type.

Comment: You can throw stones at your sysadmin until he/she configures it, too.  ;) So actually suggestion mod_rewrite for that is a bit over the top I'd say. Maybe not the first suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file config of your web server (for example, in apache the **httpd.conf** file) to interprete the .htm as it was a php file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, look for the php addHandler directive in the `apache2.conf` file and add your extension in the list. Do not forget to restart apache after.