# Using PHP in a .html document

Tags: php, html, node.js

I'm working on a job at work where I need to create a web forum. In my stupidity I decided to use javascript, not knowing beforehand that javascript is a client-side language. I need a way to save the data from the javascript onto the server and then be able to read the data. I tried looking at things like node.js, however I would have reconfigure the entire web server (which isn't mine) in order to do this. The other solution is to use php. Here's the problem: There's a bunch of includes used in the html file that set up the layout of the webpage (i.e. css files, html files, and even a php include). I can't change the name of the index file to index.php because it breaks all of the includes inside of the file. So I need a way to save, say a text file, using javascript and html. If there's a way to, I would like to do something very simple, like include a php file in the html and then call a php function in my javascript code to get the contents of the file into my index.html page. I thought there was a way to call a simple command like this:

```
<script>
    var thedata = <?php getData() ?>
</script>
```

where the php function getData() would return a json encoded string with all of the data in it (handled from a separate php file). Is there any way to do this? Any other suggestions for how to handle data storage on a server without changing my index.html file to index.php?

Note: I tried accessing the apache httpd.conf file and adding a handler to pre-process .html files as php files, but that doesn't seem to work (nothing as simple as echo 'test' works on the html file).

Comment: You should be able to add .html as a file extension for PHP to handle. It's possible however, that maybe farther up the file .html is already being assigned to text/html. I'd check to see if .html occurs anywhere else in your httpd.conf file first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add PHP code to .html files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files)

Comment: Off-topic: Be sure to *echo* output the result of getData() using json_encode(), like this `var thedata = <?php echo json_encode(getData()) ?>;` You don't have to add quotes, they will be added by json_encode()

Comment: It might be better to use Ajax to query your server as a webservice? (then you add to write your server accordingly, in PHP if you want)

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your `.htaccess`:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

[source](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/apache-handlers-running-html-as-php)

It causes Apache to treat HTML files as files that contain PHP. Be careful not to somehow accidentally use PHP syntax in a regular HTML file, though.

Remember that you'll still need to use PHP tags to enter PHP mode. This works as expected:

```
<p>html content ...  <?php echo 'hello, world'; ?></p>
```

But this will output the the echo command:

```
<p>echo 'hello, world'</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

If can make your webserver process your pages thru the mod_php.
if you are using apache just add this to your .htaccess

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm 
AddHandler php-script .php .html .htm
AddHandler php5-script .php .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

I hope you understand the repercussion of doing this. all your pages will be processed like that and the memory/cpu use of your pages will be way greater.

if this is to happen inside one single file, make sure to add it inside a  statement.

and within your example you should add:

```
<script>
    var thedata = <?php echo getData(); ?>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! Oddly though, those two AddType lines changed all of the webpages so it popped up with a screen asking to save the webpage, and then you couldn't load it. Not sure why it does that... I believe it's the "application" in "application/x-httpd-php". When I take it out it no longer breaks the webpages.

Answer (score -2):

The file extension must be `.php`, so that the server knows to parse the file.

Comment: Not necessarily... servers can be configured to process any file as PHP. See Waleed Khan's answer for details.

Comment: Please say the answer to us, so we all can get a bit smarter.