# passing php variable to html

Tags: php, html, variables

I am having a problem with passing variables. This is the code that I think should pass the $user variable to new_page.html:

```
if (mysqli_query($con,$newUser))
{
    $user = $_GET[username];
    header('Location: new_page.html?currentUser=$user');
}
else
{
    header('Location: sign up.html');
}
```

And inside the html page I try to create a link to a new page with the user variable (which has been passed in) as the text property:

```
<a href = "user_page.php"> <?php echo $currentUser ?><a/>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `new_page.html` needs to be a PHP file too, or you'll have to use JavaScript in `new_page.html` to dynamtically set the `href=""` attribute.

Comment: a file name of "sign up.html" with a space in it is going to give you all sorts of problems...

Comment: If you're going to use variables in strings (such as your header line), and want the actual value rather than the name of the variable, use double quotes (")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't process PHP in a html file. You can process HTML in a PHP file - so always use the .php extension.

I think username is meant to be a post? So:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
header('Location: page.php?user='.$username);
```

then in page.php you can use the following to collect that variable from the URL:

```
$username = $_GET['user'];
```

**An important note:**
Note the use of concatenation to add a variable into the PHP Header function:

Instead of:

```
header('Location: new_page.html?currentUser=$user');
```

use concatenation:

```
header('Location: new_page.html?currentUser='.$user);
```

if you need more variables:

```
header('Location: new_page.html?currentUser='.$user.'&anothervar='.$anotherVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem where you assign $user, too, the quotes are missing:

```
$user = $_GET['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change new_page.**html** to new_page.**php** and then :

Replace this line :

```
 <a href = "user_page.php"> <?php echo $currentUser ?><a/>
```

By :

```
 <a href = "user_page.php"> <?php echo $_GET['currentUser'] ?><a/>
```

An other thing , when you access this variable , it's value will be *$user* as string,to get it's real value , change quotes to double quotes:

```
header("Location: new_page.html?currentUser=$user");
```

See :

1. [POST and GET methods](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php)
2. [PHP in HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files)