# PHP syntax highlighting for .html files in Brackets.io Editor

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, adobe-brackets

I work with a templating engine which is powered by .html template files. These templates also allow the use of PHP. Is it possible to enable PHP syntax highlighting for .html files?

***Update***: As of Sprint 39, Brackets now allows you to include a ".brackets.json" file in your project directory which lets you map file extensions to languages.

This will let you use php syntax highlighting within a html file.

```
{
    "language.fileExtensions": {
        "html": "php"
    }
}
```

Comment: http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files

Comment: Thanks Sharad, but running the code is no problem. I just want Syntax Highlighting for the PHP code when using the brackets.io editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Update 2:* As of Brackets 0.42, this is even simpler still:

1. Open an .html file
2. Change the status bar dropdown from HTML to PHP
3. Open the dropdown again and click "Set as Default for .html Files"

---

*Earlier update:* You can now do this via a simple Brackets extension, without needing to modify the core code:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var LanguageManager = brackets.getModule("language/LanguageManager");
    var htmlLang = LanguageManager.getLanguage("html"),
        phpLang  = LanguageManager.getLanguage("php");
    htmlLang.removeFileExtension("html");
    phpLang.addFileExtension("html");
});
```

1. Put this code in a file named main.js
2. In Brackets, go to Help > Show Extensions Folder
3. Create a new folder under `user`, and place the main.js file inside it
4. Restart Brackets

Here's [more info on writing Brackets extensions](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-write-extensions), if needed.

---

*(old answer)*

Unfortunately this is tricky in Brackets currently.  Syntax highlighting is extensible in that you can assign new file extensions to a particular highlighting mode, but the ".html" extension is already in use by the plain-HTML highlighting mode.

Your best options are probably:

**a)** [Pull Brackets from git](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Hack-on-Brackets#wiki-overview) and locally patch the [languages.json](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/src/language/languages.json) file so that .html is interpreted as PHP instead. (You *could* do this in a regular installed build but it won't be fun, since that JSON file is baked into a giant minified blob). Running from a git copy isn't too hard though.

**b)** Rename all your files to reflect that they're not plain HTML. Brackets will automatically recognize ".phtml" for example, which seems like a more appropriate file extension anyway. (If there's some other extension that your templating system will use but Brackets *doesn't* recognize automatically, you can use [this trick](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/brackets-dev/FDb_zq5isF0) to register it as a PHP-type extension).