# $con->query error MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

What I'm trying to do is get my html/php code to display data from my MySQL in a table. 
It connects just find to the database, but I think I'm getting an error at: `$resultt=$con->query("SELECT DisplayName, Kills, Deaths, Wins, Lost FROM TTPlayer");`  for it always shows that code as text on the webpage when I execute it. Also in the tables it shows each of the row methods and their variable 
 Thanks in advance for any help!

**Code:**
http://pastebin.com/j1EDux5y

Executed webpage:
http://pasteboard.co/2pzqESnw.png

Comment: The answer is simple but can be because of many factors. Is the file `.php` extension? Is a webserver installed? If so, how are you accessing it, `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///file.php`?

Comment: execute the `.php` file via webserver,  make sure `php5_module` is enabled, ensure that you are not using `<?` short tags

Comment: It is a .html file, I will  check on php5_module

Comment: On `.html` you cannot execute php, On `.php` you can execute html :-)

Comment: That's wrong @MySQLRockstar, PHP can be executed in HTML files. See Fred -ii-'s answer below.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, By default we can never do that, forefully we can do if we modify  .htaccess. But why unnecessary, when .php is already there. For your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"It is a .html file, I will check on php5_module –  ZachtheBoB 2 mins ago"*

`.html` file extensions will not parse PHP directives.

A `.php` extension is required to do this, plus making sure a webserver and PHP are installed and properly configured.

If on a local machine, you will need to access it like `http://localhost/file.php` and not `file:///file.php`

You can however, instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP through `.htaccess` if that is your preference.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

If you only plan on including the PHP on one page, it is better to setup this way:

```
<Files yourpage.html>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

If you are running PHP as CGI

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

If on GoDaddy

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```