# Adding php code to .html file

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I want to add php code to my .html file. I have searched a lot and din't find why it is not working

Steps i have followed for this:

1) Created a .htaccess file inside my htdocs

2) And added the following things

```
  AddType text/html .shtml .shtm .htm .html
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5.6 .html
```

3) Restarted my Apache.

Executed my page. My page contains

```
<?php
 echo "hello";
?>
```

I din't see any errors and hello too. And i changed the htaccess content to

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files)

It is also not working. I don't know whether htaccess file must contain some other elements or not. Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Is the opening php tag just a typo? It should be without spaces: `<?php`.

Comment: Have you tested with a .php file? Does that work?

Comment: I have a .php file in the same place. It works. Do i need to something else so that it checks htaccess file

Comment: Perhaps `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html` would do the trick?

Comment: @MikeAnthony No I tried that too

Comment: Is this on a production server? If so, who's your host?

Comment: localhost. doesn't work in my system? @MikeAnthony

Comment: OS? Apache and PHP version?

Comment: Would it be worth considering just rewriting .html urls to open .php files?

Comment: @MikeAnthony OS is windows 7. php verdsion 5.6.2

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `AllowOverride` to `All` in `httpd.conf`, or in your virtual hosts file (`httpd-vhosts.conf`) if you are using them.

Otherwise, directives in your `.htaccess` file will not be allowed.

More information can be found here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

#### Update

If it is set to `All`, then you should be able to do either of the following.

Unset the handler and reset it:

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Or, use `FilesMatch`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Let me check this. `<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>
` What is that require all denied.

Comment: It should be `require all granted` - that's what I use in mine... From which file is that?

Comment: And are you using a virtual host?

Comment: No Mike. `AllowOverride All
    Require all granted` I just added this and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Please see the update in my answer. If it still doesn't work, then I might be missing something too...

Comment: When i check in the chrome browser, my php lines are automatically commented. It looks like `<1--?php  phpinfo(); ?--> <html></html>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76355/discussion-between-mike-anthony-and-gops-ab).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: Something else? is the mod_mime enabled?

Comment: Either that, or check that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` in `httpd.conf` or your virtual host file if other `htaccess` directives are not loading.

Comment: LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so is enabled. But not mod_mime magic.

Comment: @MikeAnthony it is set to None.