# Echo Image from get PHP

Tags: php, echo

I know it may sound stupid, but im trying to echo an image that i get his name from the url, i dont get anything only the alt text of the image.

This is my code

```
<?php
$url =  $_GET["userpic"];
$DisplayImg = "./Imagenes/".$url.".jpg";
?>
<html>
<body>

<img src="<?php echo $DisplayImg; ?>" alt="Error" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to give full path of the image where it exist?

Comment: [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and `var_dump();` - 2 invaluable tools at your disposal.

Comment: if you get the alt text, then your `src` url is incorrect, and the browser is getting a 404 trying to fetch it.

Comment: What is output ? or Inspect image src

Comment: $DisplayImg = "./Imagenes/"'.$url.'".jpg"; i think you need an extra '' on the .$url.

Comment: Yes is a 404 error, and i tryied with the full path too and nothing, i look in the console (dont know a nearly nothing with it) and this is the url i think is using http://mydomain./myweb/<?php%20echo%20$DisplayImg;%20?>;%20?%3E

Comment: Dante, I put your code on my server and it worked. Are you sure u got an .php file?

Comment: Var_Dump = string(35) "http://domain/Imagenes/Picture.jpg"

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalvesMachado I try it now in an .php and it work thanks, but i need it to work in a html is there any way to make so?

Comment: ^ why did I know that ^ - **A:** Instruct Apache to treat them as such.

Comment: I answered your question. Have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dante,

Change the extension to .php instead of .html

If you want to run a php code into a .html refer to [How do I add PHP code/file to HTML(.html) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-to-html-files)

Comment: Thanks, i had a html, because i was making things with google charts javascript and other stuff and because and i am newbie in that, i didnt know i could make all in a php file, thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="../Imagenes/<?php echo $_GET["userpic"]; ?>.jpg" alt="Error" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

If that still dont work then your path is wrong you can see it by adding

```
<?php echo "<a href='../Imagenes/".$_GET["userpic"].".jpg'>this should link to your image</a>"; ?>
```