# How to call php echo json variable value in html code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, facebook

I  get facebook friend list using graph API. i got answer json array. that array value store in one variable Looks like

```
   $json_output=($result['summary']['total_count']);
   echo  "$json_output";
```

this code belongs to facebook.php File .. this variable how to call in my index.html file  my html code friend list counter looks like code

```
  <div class="follow">
  <div class="col-md-6 two">
  <span>36</span>
  <p>Fiends Countrer</p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

How to call php echo variable in this html code ?  thanks in advance? i have already not Working ?

Comment: if you use javascript sdk, you can print in html

Comment: i have using php sdk sir

Comment: you can return echo content to a js file using ajax and then you can append that value to your paragraph using appentTo() method of jquery..

Comment: brother  i need to use javascript in my code?

Comment: You can decode the json array using json_decode() and take the count using count(), you will get the count of your friends.

Comment: i got answer. But i want   call this echo variable in html file

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the index.html to a php file (index.php), then you can output the variable using the echo

```
<?php echo $json_output; ?>
```

Comment: without change  html file extension its possible ?

Comment: @arasu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files