# Where to safely store database credentials within a PHP website

Tags: php, mysql, security

I am developing a website that will eventually be connecting to a mySQL database. My question is how do I safely and securely store those credentials to access that database within my PHP site without risk of them accidentally being compromised by, for example, the server returning PHP as normal text? Any help is appreciated, thanks! :)

Comment: do you mean the script's credentials used to communicate with mysql server or do you mean the users passwords, say, hashed in the db ?

Comment: The credentials to communicate with the database, sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Common practices for this problem include putting the database credentials in a configuration file that is not PHP, such as a .ini file, and then reading that with PHP. To add extra security you should also put the configuration file outside of the web root, so that you can be sure no one can access the file by navigating directly to it.

For example, the Laravel framework (among others) define the web root in the /public directory, while outside that directory is a `.env` file containing database credentials among other settings.

Have a look here for more info: [How to secure database passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97984/how-to-secure-database-passwords-in-php)

More importantly though, you should never have to worry about your PHP being served as plain text. Take the proper development precautions to ensure this never happens. Some starting points are:

- Making sure you have PHP installed!
- Make sure you open and close your tags properly
- Make sure your file extension is `.php` and not `.html` (unless you use [this work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files))
- Also make sure in production code that you aren't displaying errors on the page ([display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) ini)

Comment: how do you take the proper development precautions as you say. Help the OP to understand that. Just make it part of your answer

Comment: Do hosting services generally allow a folder outside of the web root on shared plans? Sorry if that's kinda out of the scope of the question, but I don't have a lot of experience with hosting plans. thank you for the answer  by the way!

Comment: @scarecrow850 I am not sure. I always use VPS but if you are using a service like godaddy or ipage then it is not likely. In that case, take a look at using .htaccess to block certain files from being viewed

Comment: I'm planning on using HostGator for my hosting, but I can only do the basic hosting plan, is there any risk of the .htaccess method failing and not blocking it?

Comment: Unless the file is renamed or the htaccess edited then no you will be safe

Comment: though access to the sever will also allow access to the config file