# What happen with my php code?

Tags: php, chat, blueimp

I would like to add this code on a global source of a software chat:

```
<?php
include "../../../mc.php";
include "../../../std.php";
?>
```

I put it on one file called "loggedIn.html" and "loggedOut.html", so i changed the name of both files to the extension ".php".
The point is that the software does not recognize me that simple statement, it takes as a comment, as you can see in the picture below:

[The code does not recognize my include php tag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TAtG.png)

My server support php 5.4 and all complements of the language very well.

I am a beginner programming in php and i would like to now what happened in the code, please help me.

(Sorry for my english, i am Mexican, i am studying english).

Regards,
Christopher Coria.

Comment: Are you sure your server is running php ?

Comment: Could you try adding `phpinfo()` at the top of the code to see what happens? Do you have php error reporting turned on for your code ?

Comment: Sounds like your server does not have PHP configured properly, as the code is clearly not hitting the parser at any point. You'll need to provide information about your hosting environment for more help.

Comment: Also, see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files. PHP may be running on your server but it may not have been configured to run from .html file.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: what's the extension of the file executing this code ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, sorry for the late! u.u

Comment: My server runs php 5.4, i sent a support ticket to my hosting to know what happened whit the code

Comment: The extension of the file is .php and my included external files are in .php @Pedro Lobito

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put PHP content in a file with an `.http` extension because then your webserver does not interpret PHP code as PHP but as plaintext.

I recommend to put your code in a `.php` file instead.

If there is no way to put your code into another file or change the file extension to `.php`, your can force your server to interpret HTML files as PHP files by adding the following line to your`.htaccess` files:

`AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`