# How to include a php code containing php header format/function into a HTML division

Tags: php, html, web

let this be sample.php

```
<?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("final_year_sample",$con);
    $qt=mysql_query("select * from gd_graph");
    header("Content-Type:image/jpg");
    $x_gap=40;
    $x_max=$x_gap*13;
    $y_max=250;
    $im = ImageCreate($x_max, $y_max) or die ("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
    $background_color = ImageColorAllocate($im, 234, 234, 234);
    $text_color = ImageColorAllocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
    $graph_color = ImageColorAllocate($im,25,25,250);
    $x1=0;
    $y1=0;
    $first_one="yes";
    while($nt = mysql_fetch_array($qt)){
        $x2=$x1+$x_gap;
        $y2=$y_max-$nt['sales'];

        ImageString($im,2,$x2,$y2,$nt['month'],$graph_color); 
        if($first_one=="no"){
            imageline($im,$x1, $y1,$x2,$y2,$text_color);
        }
        $x1=$x2;
        $y1=$y2;
        $first_one="no";
    }
    ImageJPEG($im);
?>
```

> the above sample.php code works well and gives the output as
>   [output generated from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AzNE.jpg)

What i wish to do is:

I want to include the sample.php in the below HTML page

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Front page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <span id="title">Prototype for vehicle Routing problem Solution</span>
            <div style="display:none;" id="graph_space">
                <?php
                    include('sample.php');
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

but i get the following error,

[Error displayed when i try to include the sample.php in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvbuG.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add PHP code/file to HTML(.html) files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include PHP files in an html file that way as html file won't recognize `<?php ?>` tags

Though you can try do this
Create a .htaccess file in directory and add this code to .htaccess file

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

or

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

It will force Apache server to parse HTML or HTM files as PHP Script

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the file a `.php` page with 'HTML within it'. Change: `page.html > page.php`

And then your include will run, it can't run on a static HTML page. Think about it, yo.