# Echo PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to show my PHP in a div in the HTML section of my web page,
here is the PHP

```
 $result = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM adopter");
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo 'AdopterID: '. $row['AdopterID'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Name: '. $row['Name'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Address: '. $row['Address'] . '<br>';
    echo 'TelephoneNumber: '. $row['TelephoneNumber'] . '<br> <br>';
```

I would like this to be displayed in my div in the HTML since it is always displaying this information at the top literally above my page instead of the blank space I want in my website design.

```
 <div class="title">
  </div>
    <title> PHP UPDATE DATA </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



</head>

    </div>
        </div>
```

I'm trying to put it into this section of the DIV in HTML

Comment: I don't see a `<div>` nor do I see the *blank space* you're referring to. You need to post all relevant code and better describe your problem with examples.

Comment: So what's not working as expected?

Comment: Instead of echoing while you're iterating through your database results, simply concatenate to a string. `$html .= 'AdopterID: ' . $row['AdopterID'] . '<br>';` and then echo out your HTML wherever you want.

Comment: You probably have to allow PHP to be run in HTML files. You can do this by most likely adding this into your `.htaccess` files. [Add PHP to HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files)

Comment: @lovermanthing _"...since it is always displaying this information at the top literally above my page..."_ - The code is executing fine. It's just not output to the desired location within the page.

Comment: Sorry I'm new at this, updated the post to where I would like it to be in my HTML section

Comment: You can't be sticking a `<div>` inside the `<head>`. That's why it's outputting "*literally at the top of the page*".

Comment: You probably want to http GET your php data and append that data in your div ...

Comment: @Joum Can you elaborate on this?...

Comment: @War10ck instead of `echo`ing with PHP, OP could instead use AJAX and simply have a php file server side which returns, ie, JSON and then place that JSON in his HTML asynchronously... Example here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: But now that I see what OP is trying to do, I'm not sure if this might help or might confuse OP even more... just my 2 cents, anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem about the understanding of the timing between the actions.

`PHP` is a server side language, so it will be processed ALWAYS before the client side language (like`html` and `css`)

so, if you cast `echo` is normal that `PHP` will put it on the top of the page (because is processed first, so printed first)

The way to do that is to assign the output to a variable and `echo` that variable is the point you need.

So instead of

```
echo 'AdopterID: '. $row['AdopterID'] . '<br>';
echo 'Name: '. $row['Name'] . '<br>';
echo 'Address: '. $row['Address'] . '<br>';
echo 'TelephoneNumber: '. $row['TelephoneNumber'] . '<br> <br>';
```

You should

```
$myvar = "";
while (youcode) {
    $myvar .= 'AdopterID: '. $row['AdopterID'] . '<br>';
    $myvar .= 'Name: '. $row['Name'] . '<br>';
    $myvar .= 'Address: '. $row['Address'] . '<br>';
    $myvar .= 'TelephoneNumber: '. $row['TelephoneNumber'] . '<br><br>';
}
```

than in some point you will have your HTML:

```
<div>
    <?php echo $myvar; ?>
</div>
```

i hope i was clear enough

Comment: Thanks for this, I just tried it and it does indeed place it in the desired area, but it only displays one record from my database instead of all of them?

Comment: i think you added the ```$myvar = "";``` inside the ```while```, so everytime the while starts a new cycle, it will override the variable. Just put it before the ```while``` statement
```$myvar = "";```
````while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){```` (i edited the main thread)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want. You need to place your output *within* the `<body>` for it to display as intended.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> PHP UPDATE DATA </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="title">
            <?php
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM adopter");
            if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
                    echo 'AdopterID: '. $row['AdopterID'] . '<br>';
                    echo 'Name: '. $row['Name'] . '<br>';
                    echo 'Address: '. $row['Address'] . '<br>';
                    echo 'TelephoneNumber: '. $row['TelephoneNumber'] . '<br> <br>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```