# php/html multi-page navbar?

Tags: php, html, css, navbar

Sorry if I sound like an idiot, but I'm relatively new to php.

Basically, I want to have a navbar that is synced across all the pages of my website.

What I have so far is this:

navbar.php

```
<?php
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> -
<ul> -
<li><a href="index.html"><div id="nav"><span id="middle">Home</span></div></a> -
<li><a href="art.html"><div id="nav"><span id="middle">Art</span></div></a></li> -
<li><a href="games.html"><div id="nav"><span id="middle">Games</span></div></a></li> -
<li><a href="wish.html"><div id="nav"><span id="middle">Wish List</span></div></a></li> -
<li><a href="dw.html"><div id="nav"><span id="middle">Doctor Who</span></div></a></li> -
</ul>'; 
?>
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Colin Site</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <style>
    p {
      font-size: 150%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navcontain">
    <?php include "nav.php"; ?>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h2>Welcome to my website, where I do random things</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

style.css

```css
#navbar {
  width: 100%;
}
#nav {
  background-color: #848482;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: white;
}
#navcontain {
  position: relative;
  top: 1%;
  background-color: alpha;
  width: 100%;
}
```

When I go to my website, there's just a blank space where my navbar should be.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If navbar.php won't contain any logic, you can omit the echo statement and just add the HTML directly to the page.

Comment: did my answer works for you? if so accept the answer you believe is the right one

Comment: Yeah, your answer works. I didn't realize how dumb I was until this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't execute PHP code in a HTML file. Look at the extension of the file where you're including the `navbar.php` it's `.html` right? It's wrong then. In order to make it works rename it to `index.php`.

Comment: Technically speaking, you're not entirely correct. *By default*, HTML files aren't preprocessed, but that can be changed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files

Comment: And I believe that's not the way to go because you're sending a simple HTML page through an interpreter just for not to change the extension :-) and therefore all the `.html` pages will go through the same interpreter even if they hasn't a line of PHP code

Answer (score 0):

You have `<?php include "nav.php"; ?>` in your HTML, but according to your question the file is named `navbar.php`....

(yes, and your main file has to  have a php ending, as @ReynierPM wrote)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using php in a html file, though you can use AJAX / JQuery to load the php into the webpage, heres an axample

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script> <!-- You can get JQuery at http://jquery.com -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
                $("#nav").load("nav.php");
            });
        </script>
        <div id="nav"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, but this workd perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, feel free to put this as an answer @BRFNGRNBWS