# how can i add wordpress posts into my html site the blog is located at myurl.com/blog

Tags: php, wordpress, integration, blogs

How can I add wordpress posts into my html site the blog is located at myurl.com/blog I have looked online but I don't see any comprehensive tutorials. So I want to be able to have a section on my site that will fetch the posts from the wordpress page, any help would be greatly appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: Is your HTML site and the WordPress site on the same host?

Comment: Yes my website and Wordpress are hosted at the same site.. I have my main .com and the Wordpress is installed to the .com/blog folder

Comment: Is the blog myurl.com/blog already an existing WordPress site or are you trying to create it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is in the WordPress Codex: [Integrating WordPress with Your Website « WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website).

It doesn't get any simpler. Call the wp-blog-header.php file in the header of the index.html file of your html site.

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

And then use a standard loop to load posts on the page you want to show the posts:

```
<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

**Update:**

To determine if PHP is running on your server, use FTP to upload a plain text file called phpinfo.php with only this line in it and no whitespace at the top of the file:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Then go to yoursite.com/phpinfo.php - or yoursite.com/somefolder/phpinfo.php and you should see a screenfull of PHP configurations. If you don't, PHP is not running. Ask GoDaddy about it.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, its like the php doesn't work within my html site/

Comment: What's the webhost? Is php enabled?

Comment: hi, it says I have PHP Version 7.1.16 when I uploaded the php file so it is enabled... the loop for whatever reason doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: where is the header of the index.html file, I have been putting the first piece of code at the extreme top of the index.html file, should I located somewhere lower?

Comment: Ok, php is running. The header call goes at the top of index.html, with the `<?php` and `?>` around it. You should look in your php error log to see what might be wrong; where the log is depends on your system.

Comment: hi, I have contacted my host provider and they advised you can only use php within a .php file and not into html.. would you know if this is correct?

Comment: Search SE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files

Comment: Hey thank you so much for everything!! Really appreciate it 