# Sending an HTML email on a PHP code gives me a Syntax Error

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, syntax

Good morning, I'm having problems when I execute my code, I think I'm having problems with the quotes, etc.

So far this is what I've tried and I'm stil having syntax error with this specific line of codes.

```html
$message .= "if ($row['status']) :
          $output .= '<td>'.$row["status"].'</td> ';
       else:
          $output .= '
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="'.$row['reqnumber'].'" />
                        <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
                    </form>
                </td>";
```

Here's what it looks like right now:

[Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kT0h.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a42gY.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have the logic and the quotes wrong, maybe this is what you want :

```
if ($row['status']) :
            $output .= '<td>'.$row["status"].'</td> ';
            else:
            $output .= '
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="'.$row['reqnumber'].'" />
                    <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
                </form>
            </td>';
endif;
$message .= $output;
```

Comment: This is totally different

Comment: @WadeBoar To be honest, I'm still confused on what you want to achieve

Comment: Actually I tried your code, but the email won't work anymore. But the color coding was good, might be another syntax error?

Comment: Attached the error pic, really appreciate your help btw!

Comment: @WadeBoar may I know what is the purpose of the conditional? (since the `$row` variable is not exist)

Answer (score 0):

As Hasta Dhana had answered, here is some detail about why he change the code completely.

this code you use

```html
$message .= "if ($row['status']) :
          $output .= '<td>'.$row["status"].'</td> ';
       else:
          $output .= '
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="update-request-status.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="'.$row['reqnumber'].'" />
                        <button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""><span>New Request!</span></button>
                    </form>
                </td>";
```

make your $message output exactly how you write the code, because php doesn't define is as process code. this `""` is to inform the php code processor that what you write is string not process. Also please refer [INFO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files.) to learn more about how to use html in php.

**After Edit**
can you check the spelling of your array.