# PHP code not working when I move it to a different HTML code so that to access same database

Tags: php, html

I have a front end HTML code which I have used PHP to access the database and it worked well. The problem came  when I used the same PHP code to access the same database but with different HTML frontend code. My php code appears grayed out on the editor, see the image

[image]

I am trying to access same database. whats the problem here

Comment: **Don't post code as images.** Copy/paste the code into the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `php` files use php extention like `index.php` you have `index.html`

[How do I add PHP code/file to HTML(.html) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312316/how-do-i-add-php-code-file-to-html-html-files)

Comment: wow. Thank you, I was so focussed on code errors until I didn't think of the file extension.

Comment: If you are just going to reference another Stackoverflow question for the solution, this should be marked as a duplicate as it adds nothing to the original solution.

Comment: @LivingstoneM sometimes we miss small but important case :)

Comment: If you look at the linked questions, there is a lot more information than just change the file extension.  If I just answered every question that I close as a duplicate then I would get the bonus from that, but SO would be full of questions partially answered and don't have the benefit of the time spent on the duplicate.